# Access 2016 linked picture path lost after closing and reopening the database

Tags: vba, forms, image, ms-access

1 main form, containing 2 subforms:
first subform, datasheet view: list of employees; second subform, single form view: contact details and photo.

frmContactDetails has a image (inserted using design>controls>image), which contolsource is linked to the employee photo path.

frmEmployee, On Current event: requery frmContactDetails.

I linked a blank photo in image.picture property.

Everything works well, I can select any employee and see all détails and photo updating according to the current record. I can do a compact and repair, reopen the main form, and it is still working.

**Problem: When I close and reopen the database, photos are not updating anymore.** In design view, image.picture property still shows the complete blank photo path in the field, but when I clic to the 3 dots button, it does not reach the folder conatining this photo. I need to set again the correct path, save and reopen the form to make it work again.

I've been trying to find a solution for hours without success.

frmEmployee record source:

```
SELECT tblEmployee.Email, tblEmployee.EmployeeName FROM tblEmployee;
```

frmEmployee OnCurrent event:

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
Me.Parent.txtEmployeeEmail.Value = Me.Email
Me.Parent.frmContactDetail.Requery
End Sub
```

frmContactDetails record source:

```
SELECT tblPhotos.Email, tblPhotos.PhotoName
FROM tblPhotos
WHERE (((tblPhotos.Email)=[Forms]![frmMain]![txtEmployeeEmail]));
```

frmContactDetails image:   control source: PhotoName, picture type: Linked, Size Mode: clip, Picture property:

```
C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\test\BlankImage.bmp
```

Do you have an idea on what could be wrong?

Additional information:

All pictures are in .png format (except the BlankImage.bmp). I found a piece of code to load .png images in my custom ribbon and it works well. Pictures are stored in a subfolder of temp folder. I think this piece of code uses API and it is too complex for me to understand: I tried to use the same function to load images into the form without success. In tblEmployee, there is an attachment with .png photo. At first, I tried to link the Image control to this attachment, but it does not display photos. Then I copied images Inside a folder of the temp folder, and used the .Picture property to display photo Inside the image control. I added a Field to tbl Employee with PhotoName. A textbox in the form is linked to this field, and then I recreate the full path using Environ("temp")\photofolder[PhotoName].png. If there is no path in .Picture (in design view) it is set to (none) and image control do not refresh. I give the path to BlankPhoto in design view, and then all updates correctly when I use the form. The problem is if I close Access and re-open it, BlankPhoto path is still visible in .Picture but when I click on the three dots button the file picker starts in Document folder (the path is lost), and photos do not update correctly.

What would be the correct way to go?

Comment: If you have you have ControlSource dynamically displaying employee photo from external folder, why are you using Picture property?

Comment: Thank you for your reply June7. All pictures are in .png format (except the BlankImage.bmp). I found a piece of code to load .png images in my custom ribbon and it works well. Pictures are stored in a subfolder of temp folder. I think this piece of code uses API and it is too complex for me to understand. I tried to use the same function to load images into the form without success.

Comment: @June7: I added information in my initial post because of character limitation. Could you please check and help me?

Comment: I have never used Picture property for dynamically loading images to form or report. I have never used VBA to dynamically load images. This was necessary up to Access 2003 but then MS added the ControlSource property to Image control. I have only used ControlSource property. The ControlSource can be bound to Attachment field (drag from the design Field List onto form or report) or can reference external image file path concatenated to a field with file name - which you appear to be doing.

Comment: However, complication seems to be you need to load alternate file with different image extension. Can you convert the bmp to a png?

Comment: It works well now, with png directly from tblEmployee, not the one copied to temp foler: I just had to insert an attachment control in the form and bind it to tblEmployee attachment. It is possible to display a picture in an attachment control, but all the time I thought I had to use the picture control.